# I'm try to upload file using node.js to aws but i don't know what went wrong with my code

Tags: javascript, node.js, body-parser, multer-s3

1. app.js file:

   ```
   var aws = require('aws-sdk'),
       http = require('http'),
       bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
       fs = require('fs'),
       path = require('path'),
       methodOverride = require("method-override"),
       express = require('express');

   var app = new express();

   app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
   app.set('view engine', 'jade');
   app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
   app.use(bodyParser.json());
   app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
   app.use(methodOverride("_method"));

   var config_path = path.join(__dirname, 'auth.json');

   aws.config.loadFromPath(config_path);
   var s3 = new aws.S3();

   app.get('/buckets', function(req, res){
     s3.listBuckets(function (err, data) {
       res.json(data);
     });

   });

   app.get('/upload', function (req, res) {
     res.render('upload');
   });

   app.post('/upload', function (req, res) {
     var s3request = {
       Body: fs.readFileSync(req.files.theFile.path),
       Bucket: 'bucket-*********',
       Key: req.files.theFile.name
       };

   s3.putObject(s3request, function (err, data) {
       res.render('upload', {done: true});
     });
   });

   const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;
   app.listen(PORT);

   module.exports = app;
   ```
2. layout.jade:

   ```
   doctype html
   html
     head
       title intra
       link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/bootstrap.min.css')
     body
       block content
   ```
3. upload.jade:

   ```
   extends layout

   block content
     div.container
       if (done)
         p Upload complete
       h3 Upload File
       form(enctype="multipart/form-data", method="post")
        label Photo:
           p
             input(type="file", name="theFile")
           input(type="submit", value="Submit")
   ```

run. TypeError: Cannot read property 'theFile' of undefined.

Answer (score 1):

I did not run any test to confirm but from reviewing the code I see that you are attempting to access an array.

```
Key: req.files.theFile.name
```

`req.files` is an array hence you may want to refactor your code to be:

```
Key: req.files[0].name
```

This is assuming you are uploading only a single file.

You can use this example for reference
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-photo-album.html